# SQL query against "bad word" filter list

Tags: sql

My client wants to maintain a list of "bad words" that they can check auto-generated usernames against.  This way, someone named "Fred Uckman" can be automatically rolled over to a different username format.

Given a particular input (@username nvarchar(60)), how best can I query against a single column table to see if that input contains any of the "bad words" in that table?

Comment: `Classic` -> `Clbuttic`? Good luck...

Comment: Poor Mr. Uckman, always mocked, even by database engineers :(

Comment: Oh, for Fred's sake! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a table with a single column and your bad words

```
select count(*) from BadWords
where @userName like '%'+theBadWord+'%'
```

Comment: That does it perfectly!  Thank you.

Comment: What if a bad word can be a part of a normal word? I currently have no suitable example but I come from another language which there are these kinds of words. But for making it easy to understand, assume that the word 'inter' is a bad word, but it's part of the word 'pointer' or 'international'. Your solution will filter out both words which is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a trigger for this. If you store the "bad words" in a table, and the destination usernames in another table, the trigger could run automatically "BEFORE INSERT" into the destination usernames table. To actually match the "bad word" you could use it as an operand to the LIKE SQL keyword. You could concatenate wildcards % (multiple characters) or _ ( a single character) to the beginning or end with CONCAT. Also, to create a trigger, you could use [these steps](http://www.qualitestgroup.com/howTo/How-to-create-an-SQL-trigger).