# applying python function to sql

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I'm trying to apply the following function

```
def flagged_word(word):
    flaggedWords = ['online','official','call','fantasy','contact','installation', 
                    'pay', 'manufacturer', 'delivery', 'established', 'registration',
                    'seo', 'service', 'customers', 'trading', 'company', 'buy', 'sell', 
                    'escort', 'provider', 'product', 'patients', 'website', 'sites', 
                    'free', 'affordable', 'website', 'buisness', 'installed', 'install',
                    'management', 'manufacture', 'install', 'download', 'provides',
                    'downloaded', 'services', 'development', 'drug', 'top', 'reviews',
                    'review', 'treatment', 'deliver', 'hire', 'hiring', 'supply', 
                    'supplier', 'commercial', 'discount', 'account', 'websites', 'app', 
                    'products', 'guests', 'deals']
    count = len(flaggedWords)
    counter = 0
    while counter <= count:
        #print(word.lower())
        if word.lower() == flaggedWords[counter]:
            return True
            break
        else: 
            counter = counter + 1
        if counter == count:
            return False
```

to an sql queryed value from a database that will return a user id and a description in python. I want to put the description through this function and then use an sql query to return the remaining users. How do a make that happen?

Comment: Are you saying you want to query the users who does not have these words in the description column ?

Comment: Also you can have the function `return word.lower() in flaggedWords` instead of writing this loop and counters.

Comment: I think it must be a DB operation, rather than client logic. Follow the approach in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23068963/995052